# Image target rotating on play - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've been tearing my hair out with this one all week. I am building on Unity for Android, and every time I press play to test my project with my webcam, when it detects the image target, it seems to change rotation! I'm not sure if this is supposed to happen, but my problem is manifesting with my Skybox not rotating with the image target, so my scene is all messed up, instead of my sky being up, it's sideways, if that makes sense. If you help me solve this you will forever have bought my friendship and loyalty, lol, seriously though, I'm losing it, it was working fine before, please help me. Alan.

I am using Enviro for my skybox, I tried rotating it and the camera, I installed a new version of Unity, deleted cache, and tried writing a script that rotates the skybox with the camera, I'm terrible at coding, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Sounds like, that you don't want to swap between portrait- and landscape modes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.